# Theos fails to compile tweak after adding preference bundle

Tags: ios, cydia, theos

I am trying to add a preference bundle to a tweak I am building. I followed the part of [this tutorial](http://blog.aehmlo.com/2012/08/03/new-tweak-readme) where they add the preference bundle. After I tried adding the preference bundle, my tweak fails to compile with the following error:

```
Making all for tweak MyTweak...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
 Linking tweak MyTweak...
 Stripping MyTweak...
 Signing MyTweak...
Making all in prefs...
Making all for bundle prefs...
 Copying resource directories into the bundle wrapper...
 Compiling prefs.mm...
cc1objplus: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSListController.h:9,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSLocaleController.h:8,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/Preferences.h:9,
                 from prefs.mm:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSViewController.h:47: warning: property ‘specifier’ type does not match protocol ‘PSController’ property type
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSViewController.h:47: warning: property ‘rootController’ type does not match protocol ‘PSController’ property type
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSSetupController.h:7,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSInternationalLanguageSetupController.h:7,
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/Preferences.h:24,
                 from prefs.mm:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Headers/PSRootController.h:71: warning: property ‘specifier’ type does not match protocol ‘PSController’ property type
make[3]: *** [obj/prefs.mm.ade1d157.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [internal-bundle-all_] Error 2
make[1]: *** [prefs.all.bundle.variables] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versions of the headers may be messed up, since they're Private Framework headers, not official Apple headers.

Two possible solutions:

1. Redownload the headers from a better source. [rpetrich's versions](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders) are often recommended.
2. If that doesn't work, edit the headers manually to fix the problem. Find the header containing the `PSController` protocol (probably PSController.h), check what type `specifier` is supposed to be, and then make the change in `PSViewController.h`. I believe I had to do something like this the first time I was dealing with Preference Bundles.

Comment: Thanks. I tried solution 1 and just got more errors so I reverted back to the files I had before and was going to try solution 2. While looking at the header files I noticed that iOSOpenDev modified them (I installed iOSOpenDev awhile ago to try out and I'm not using it currently). I decided to just reinstall Xcode (including the iOS SDK) and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Issue resolved. I reinstalled Xcode then downloaded rpetrich's headers to $THEOS/include and also had to cp /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceAPI.h IOSurface/. Then I got the following errors:

/Volumes/Data/Users/derek/iOSProjects/calleridname/theos/include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h:251: error: ‘xpc_object_t’ does not name a type
/Volumes/Data/Users/derek/iOSProjects/calleridname/theos/include/IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h:255: error: ‘xpc_object_t’ was not declared in this scope

I just commented those lines out and it compiled successfully.